# Why div position is changing in different locale?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am working in multiple locale project where I am using same CSS for all locale (48 locale).
but in some locale div position is changing automatically, how I can fix that.

**E.g** : en_gb, de_de is working properly but sv_se locale gives different output of div position.

1.en_gb screenshot
[image]

2. sv_se screenshot
   [image: sv_se screenshot]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px)  {

    .blahyear,
    .termscondition,
    .privacy,
    .generaldata {
        padding:0% 5% 2% 7%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {
    .blahyear{margin-top: 97px;;}
    .privacy{margin-top: -139px;}
    .generaldata{margin-top: -101px;}
    .termscondition{margin-top: 136px;
        margin-left: -162px;}
    .footerNav{ margin-top: 20px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="footerText footerNav">
                <ul id="footer_ul">
                    <li class="blahyear"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" id="blah" i18n="@@blahblah">blah-blah {{showYear}}</a></li>
                    <li class="termscondition"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" id="footerTerms" i18n="@@terms_conditions">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a></li>
                    <li class="privacy"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" i18n="@@information_privacy">YOUR INFORMATION AND PRIVACY</a></li>
                    <li class="generaldata"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" i18n="@@data_protection">GENERAL DATA PROTECTION REGULATION</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Here it is added CSS and html

Answer (score 0):

It is because when using values in `%` the measurements are done relative to the `width/height` of container(can also be body) . So if you resizes browser window the sizes changes so measurements also changes .

Here measurements changes according to body.

To prevent this you can use absolute values like in `px` `cm` ..... in `padding` property

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  .tomtomyear,
  .termscondition,
  .privacy,
  .generaldata {
    padding: 0 5px 2px 7px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {
  .tomtomyear {
    margin-top: 97px;
    ;
  }
  .privacy {
    margin-top: -139px;
  }
  .generaldata {
    margin-top: -101px;
  }
  .termscondition {
    margin-top: 136px;
    margin-left: -162px;
  }
  .footerNav {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footerText footerNav">
  <ul id="footer_ul">
    <li class="tomtomyear"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" id="tomtom" i18n="@@tomtom">&copy;TOMTOM {{showYear}}</a></li>
    <li class="termscondition"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" id="footerTerms" i18n="@@terms_conditions">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a></li>
    <li class="privacy"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" i18n="@@information_privacy">YOUR INFORMATION AND PRIVACY</a></li>
    <li class="generaldata"><a (click)="reloadIfSamePage($event);" i18n="@@data_protection">GENERAL DATA PROTECTION REGULATION</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```